# Is autherize.net payment gateway secure with Magento 2.4.2?

Tags: magento2, php-7, authorize.net

I want to use a one time subscription extension. My Magento store version is 2.4.2 . Most of the extensions do not support Authrize.net payment gateway.

Is autherize.net payment gateway not secure with Magento 2.4.2 ?

Thanks,
Digvijay Singh

Comment: I am using paradoxlabs extension, and found no issue

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am also using it but i need a subscription extension to sell trial products. I will detect money for trial products after 30 days. Please suggest an extension which support Authrize.net payment